# How do i assign the return data from MySql to a C# variable?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013, count

I am trying to acquire the count of a column in my database.

```
string cmdstr = "select count(" + col + ") from " + tbname + " where \"" +
    col + "\" =\"" + val + "\"";
```

However, I do not know how to assign the count value to an int.

Comment: Look into the ExecuteReader() method of the SqlCommand. It will execute the command and then you can call .Read() to get values: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, look into Parameters. Your code is open to Sql Injection, which is very dangerous and bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

`var myVariable = new MySqlCommand("SELECT 3 FROM table WHERE id = 1",`

`databaseCon);`

`int id = (int)myVariable.ExecuteScalar();`

Cast your teturn value and assign it to Int type variable

If you want more help inform me

Comment: When casting "myVariable" to an int. An error pops up saying "Specified cast is not valid." @MeshBoy

Comment: try to cast your code variable. i was given an example.

Comment: Maybe the field you are retrieving is not an int?

Comment: COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group, including NULL values and duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is able to help you:

```
var result = Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This was suggested to me on one of my SQL questions, when I asked as to why doing it like this rather then just typing `Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`. He explained to me that this way you get a variable saying how many rows were affected.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way, ExecuteScalar to get the value or you can get DataSet

1. ExecuteScalar

   int result = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
2. DataSet

   MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

   DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

   mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

   int result = Convert.ToInt32(DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["YourFieldName"].Tostring());